# Wordpress admin page keeps loading

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Earlier i couldnt access the admin page using example.com/wp-admin so tried /wp-login.php. I have tried to delete the .htaccess file. I have tried resetting passwords from cpanel and have also defined the URLs in wp-config.php but can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Any suggestions would be great.

[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6yhd.png)
[After hitting login this is the only thing I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0lH0.png)

Comment: The [standard rules for troubleshooting this](https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/) are to deactivate all plugins and switch back to a core theme. Then, one-by-one, reactive and refresh the admin area.

Comment: You can see the error that is happening when the problem is there. look at the error in the console and begin to determine the solution. Command+Option+J (Brave Browser, when the problem occurs)